# How to sort references in the order of .tex file in cleanthesis layout?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cleanthesis

I downloaded the [cleanthesis](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) template and run LaTeX on `thesis-example.tex`. The bibliography is printed according to the alphabetical order of author's names. However, I don't want any type of sorting. I want the references to appear in the order I cited them in my LaTeX file. I have tried using `unsrt` and `sorting=none`, but none of these worked.

Comment: Welcome, the loading of some packages is done in a not so nice way. Setting up a good template is hard, because users always do stuff an author could never foresee. Add right before loading `\input{my-thesis-setup}`: `\PassOptionsToPackage{sorting=none}{biblatex}`. Of course, you need to set `bibstyle=numeric,` as well.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cleanthesis` already loads package `biblatex` for you. In order to have no sorting at all, which means the references are printed in the order they are cited, you have to add `\PassOptionsToPackage{sorting=none}{biblatex}` right before you load package `cleanthesis`.
 Alternatively, use `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=none}` after loading package `cleanthesis`.

Advice: Do this only with numerical bibliography styles. It is pointless with an alphabetical style.