# Bibliography with page number references of citations

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, pdftex

I'm trying to find a way to have my bibliography with page number of all its citations.. something similar to this..

```
Author A, Author B, author C, ”yet another amazing paper" amazing  conference, 2014. Cited on pages 97, 99 & 105.
```

Question of curiosity, does LaTeX provide some way to have the references in the order of first occurrence?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[square, sort, numbers, authoryear,backref=true,backrefstyle=none, hyperref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=True,
  citecolor=Green,
  linkcolor=Red,
  urlcolor=Blue,
  linktoc=all,
  }


\begin{document}

test~\cite{texbook}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references} 


\end{document}
```

references

```
@BOOK{texbook,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {{\TeX}book}",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984 }
```

Comment: Since you are german: http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the following along with the hints from the template itself.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{backref=true,backrefstyle=none}{biblatex}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index,biblatex,]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\addbibresource{References/references.bib} % Path to your References.bib file
```

Comment: `./thesis.tex:156: Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.
./thesis.tex:162: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

This is the error i got..

Comment: @tandem *along with the hints from the template itself.* Read what the template tells you along those lines.

Comment: Ok, Let me figure out. If i do, I'll let repost here

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is backreferences. Since you gave no MWE I cannot know what you're using for your bibliography.

There's a package `backref` for natbib, if you're using it, you can find more about it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15977/90297).

If you are using biblatex, then there's the `backref` option, you'll have to call

```
\usepackage[backref=true,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
```

you can find more information about the style in the [biblatex documentation](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: The MWE is given in the hyperlink. I'm using biblatex, and the command you gave me generates a few errors.

`Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
Error: Command \citename already defined.
Error: Command \bibfont already defined.
Error: Command \Citeauthor already defined.`

Comment: @tandem Add `custombib` within the brakets when loading the class.

Comment: @tandem Or use the approach given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308718/how-to-sort-references-in-the-order-of-tex-file

Comment: @Johannes_B, i'm using bibtex, it is still raising the same issue with `custombib` added in the brackets. 

`Package xkeyval Error: custombib undefined in families blx@opt@pre.`

Comment: @tandem Which version are you using? Please provide a minimal working example in the question. The edit button is on the left of your name.

Comment: @Johannes_B: The MWE can be found here :-) is there something I am missing

Comment: @tandem You did *not* provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- Link).

Comment: @Johannes_B: Please find it here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/veg1x1unhvj401g/AADKE9UIku5Pf12rBL-rn5Jca?dl=0

In Preamble/preamble.tex in line 124

Comment: @tandem personally, i don't use dropbox. Please edit your minimal working example to the question. Your dropbox link will go foul one day, the MWE in the question will stay. Without the MWE, the question is pointless.

Comment: Added. Sorry for the dropbox link